# How to adapt the "load-later" widget to the Laravel 4 framework

Tags: jquery, widget, laravel, laravel-4

I am trying to adapt the "widget" functionality shown here: http://julienrenaux.fr/demo/load-more-jquery.php

to Laravel 4.

My question is, how do I adapt the php code to the framework?

I have a model that outputs the data for the request:

```
public static function friend_activity_json() {
        $friend_activity = DB::table('fanartists')
                        ->join('fans', 'fanartists.fan_id', '=', 'fans.id')
                        ->join('artists', 'fanartists.artist_id', '=', 'artists.id')
                        ->orderBy('fanartists.created_at', 'DESC')
                        ->select('fans.fbid', 'fans.first_name', 'fans.last_name', 'fans.gender', 'fans.city', 'fanartists.artist_id', 'artists.stage_name', 'fanartists.created_at')
                        ->get();

        $posts = $json_encode($friend_activity);

        return $posts;

    }
```

Then, how do I use this to work the other portion of that example?  I assume make a function in the controller?  Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The example uses sessions. Getting sessions data in Laravel 4 is as simple as:

```
Session::put('key', 'value');
$value = Session::get('key');
```

For the Ajax URLs, it's easiest to set these to your controller urls. See http://four.laravel.com/docs/controllers

However, you could also use routes to achieve the same thing, see http://four.laravel.com/docs/routing

I'd also personally change the "initialPosts" sremove the following part:

```
// place the initial posts in the page
postHandler(initialPosts);
```

and instead output the initial posts directly on the page, then replace that when the "more" button is clicked.